# Using Perl and MySql, how can I check for an empty result?

Tags: mysql, perl

Way oversimplified example:

```
# Get Some data
$query = $db->prepare(qq{
    select * from my_table where id = "Some Value"
});
$query->execute;

# Iterate through the results
if ( *THE QUERY HAS RETURNED A RESULT* ) {
    print "Here is list of IDs ";
    while ($query_data = $query->fetchrow_hashref) {
        print "$query_data->{id}";
    }
};
```

Looking for the code for "THE QUERY HAS RETURNED A RESULT" up there. I'd like to avoid using count(*) in my SQL if possible, since that will require a "group by".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
$sth->execute();

my $header = 0;
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    print "Here is list of IDs:\n" if !$header++;
    print "$row->{id}\n";
}
```

Alternative:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
$sth->execute();

my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
print "Here is list of IDs:\n" if $row;
while ($row) {
    print "$row->{id}\n";
    $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
}
```

Simpler code at the expense of memory:

```
my $ids = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref($stmt);

if (@$ids) {
    print "Here is list of IDs:\n";
    print "$_\n" for @$ids;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like your check for the query result is redundant.  Your while loop will evaluate 'false' if there is no row to fetch.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking to also skip the line 'print "Here is a list of IDs ";' which is outside the loop.

Comment: @LukeTO there are other good ways to deal with that issue, e.g. `print "Here is the list of IDs " unless $already::printed::header++;`

Comment: @mob I'm a total perl noob- what are you referencing with "$already::printed::header++"? I like how readable that would be in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

**old/wrong answer**

If you are using `DBI` with `DBD::mysql` then `$query->rows;` will return you the number of rows, selected (or affected on a writing statement) by your statement.

**EDIT**

### Please don't use that and have a look at the comment to this answer by @Luke The Obscure

Comment: I don't think that works for MySQL.

Rows: "Returns the number of rows changed (updated, deleted, etc.) by the last command. This is usually used after a non-SELECT execute statement."

Let me know if I'm misinformed.

Comment: @Luke, thx for the hind. A sentence later: "For "SELECT" statements, it is generally not possible to know how many rows will be returned except by fetching them all.  Some drivers will return the number of rows the application has fetched so far, but others may return
       -1 until all rows have been fetched.  So use of the "rows" method or $DBI::rows with "SELECT" statements is not recommended." Sry, my fault, we use this in some scripts, as it works for us as expected, but we better should not!